# Exporting variable with a specific log

Tags: linux, shell, export, ksh, assign

### Problematic

Exporting a variable can be done in KSH via the command:

```
export EXAMPLE1="A"
export EXAMPLE2="B"
export EXAMPLE3="C"
```

However I want to `echo` the user that the variable has been redefined:

```
echo ${!EXAMPLE1@}" -> "$EXAMPLE1
echo ${!EXAMPLE2@}" -> "$EXAMPLE2
echo ${!EXAMPLE3@}" -> "$EXAMPLE3
```

The aim is to do both actions **in a single line of code** because I have several environment variables to assign.

### What I've done

To answer the problem, I have made a `define` function that combines both commands:

```
define() {
    var=$1
    val=$2

    export var=$val
    echo ${!var@}" -> "$var
}

EXAMPLE1="A"
EXAMPLE2="B"
EXAMPLE3="C"

define $EXAMPLE1 "X"
define $EXAMPLE2 "Y"
define $EXAMPLE3 "Z"
```

But it doesn't give the expected result. Instead of receiving:

```
EXAMPLE1 -> X
EXAMPLE2 -> Y
EXAMPLE3 -> Z
```

, I receive the following output:

```
var -> X
var -> Y
var -> Z
```

, and the environment variables are still set to `A`, `B` and `C`. It seems that my method assigns the local variable `var` instead of my environment variable.

What could be a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Don't call your function with `$EXAMPLE1` but with `EXAMPLE1`.
I made more modifications:

```
define() {
    var=$1
    val=$2
    export $var=$val
    echo "${var} -> ${val}"
}

EXAMPLE1="A"
EXAMPLE2="B"
EXAMPLE3="C"

define EXAMPLE1 "X"
define EXAMPLE2 "Y"
define EXAMPLE3 "Z"
```